# Adding title and subheadings to histogram in r keeps failing

Tags: r, histogram

I am brand new to R and I've been trying to look around StackOverflow for an answer but have not found something that works. I would like to add a title and color to my histogram graph but it keeps on failing for some reason. I've made my data in descending order and I'd like to title both the main heading and the x-axis and y-axis with differing names. Thank you so much in advance!

Here is the code that I am using:

```
CompaniesOrder=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
                 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26)
GpMean=c(9905.5789474, 8794.1052632, 4893.0526316, 3723.1052632,
  3045.6069474,1518.0444211,1200.4994211,842.4464737,765.5630588,
  647.6224211,543.739875,324.5206316,217.9081579,213.0212857,
  168.1743158,149.2178947,136.6547895,90.5400526,66.8915333,
  57.7370526,8.3272143,3.3801053,0.2194286,0,0,0)

GpMeanTreatment <- data.frame(CompaniesOrder, GpMean)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(GpMeanTreatment, aes(x = CompaniesOrder, y = GpMean)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: Take a quick look at the `ggplot` webpage https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(GpMeanTreatment, aes(x = CompaniesOrder, y = GpMean, fill = CompaniesOrder)) + 
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low='red', high='yellow') +
  labs(x = "Your X axis title", y = "Your Y axis title", title = "Your Main Title")
```

Hint: `geom_bar(stat="identity")` is just a long way of using `geom_col()`

[image]

Comment: If you're already using `labs`, you don't need `ggtitle`, just `labs(x = "X", y = "Y", title = "Your Main Title")` is enough